# How to get Parameter Store Parameters by path when using Lambda Layer?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-parameter-store

How to get *all* parameter name value pairs with a single call to AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension (`arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:015030872274:layer:AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension:4`)

i.e. Equivalent call to this AWS CLI to non Lambda Layer SSM Parameter Store:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/service1/prod" --recursive
```

Instead of this piece of code (c# / .net6) where for each key a request/response is being made:

```
var stage = "prod";
var awsSessionToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN");
var request = new RestRequest(
        "http://localhost:2773/systemsmanager/parameters/get",
        Method.Get
    )
    .AddHeader("X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token", awsSessionToken)
    .AddQueryParameter("withDecryption", true);
Log.Information("{@Request}", request);
var keys = new string[] {
    $"/service1/{stage}/key1",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key2",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key3",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key4",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key5",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key6",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key7",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key8",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key9",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key10",
    $"/service1/{stage}/key11",
};
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    var _request = request
        .AddOrUpdateParameter("name", key, ParameterType.QueryString);
    var _response =
        await restClient.ExecuteGetAsync<ParameterResponse>(_request);
    Parameters.Add(new Parameter(_response.Data.Parameter.Name,
            _response.Data.Parameter.Value
        )
    );
}
```

Please note that I can implement the flow in C#, I just can't find the specifics of the API more detailed than in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html#ps-integration-lambda-extensions-sample-commands).

Answer (score 1):

The `AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension` layer does not have the capability to retrieve SSM parameters based on a `path` value. Instead, it expects a `name` parameter in the query string, so you can retrieve only one record at a time based on the SSM parameter name.

If you want to retrieve SSM parameters based on a `path` value, then you can use the following NuGet package, which enables you to retrieve multiple configuration values simultaneously from the SSM parameter store.

```
Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager
```

The mentioned Amazon Systems Manager NuGet package utilizes the .NET `ConfigurationBuilder` to process the configuration values from the SSM parameter store. In order to access the `ConfigurationBuilder`, you also need to include the following NuGet packages in your lambda function.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

Here is a sample code snippet that shows how to retrieve configuration values from the SSM parameter store based on the `path` value:

```
public class FunctionHandler
{
    private readonly AppConfig _appConfig;
    
    public FunctionHandler()
    {
        var configurations = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddSystemsManager(cs =>
            {
                cs.Path = "/service1/prod";
                cs.ReloadAfter = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            })
            .Build();
        // Define AppConfig to match your SSM path hierarchy  
        var config = configurations.Get<AppConfig>();
    }

    public string Handle(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_appConfig);
    }
```

p.s. To retrieve configuration values by the path in your Lambda function, you should grant the following IAM role permission: `ssm:GetParametersByPath`

Comment: `Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager` would still try to fetch the params from the actual SSM not the layer though, right?

Comment: Yes, it will fetch configs directly from the SSM parameter store, not through the lambda layer/extension.